# Timedelta argument difference?

Tags: python

Actually why is this one works for input 2016 4 20 and 14:

```
import datetime
y, m, d = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
a = datetime.date(y, m, d) + datetime.timedelta(days = int(input()))
print(a.year, a.month, a.day)
```

But this one with same input returns 2016 4 28

```
import datetime
y, m, d = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
d = int(input())
a = datetime.date(y, m, d) + datetime.timedelta(days = d)
print(a.year, a.month, a.day)
```

Correct should be 2016 5 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point is the name of the variable `d`, if you change the name of `d` in something else the code will print the same result. This because you already used in `y, m, d = [int(i) for i in input().split()]`